# Are these sentences phrased correctly?

Tags: грамматика, падежи

Здравствуйте, I have begun to study Russian and I would like to know if these sentences are grammatically correct and naturally phrased?

Студе́нты посеща́ют шко́лу в оживлённом го́роде.

Мои́ носки́ лежа́т на полу́, потому́ что я сли́шком лени́в, что́бы забра́ть их.

Еле́на в ста́ром кинотеа́тре; она́ смо́трит фильм «До́ктор Жива́го» со свои́м дру́гом, Катей.

Вчера́, он ду́мал об изуче́нии кита́йского языка́, но я сказа́л ему́ откла́дывать реше́ние до утра́, потому́ что я ду́маю э́то сли́шком сло́жный.

Спасибо!

Comment: this is not homework-correction resource. even if it is not a homework - please, tend ask one question per post (non of the examples above is a good on-topic question though)

Comment: First 2 are correct. In the third should be used подруга (feminine noun) rather than друг (masculine noun). The last sentence is completely wrong (punctuation, verb, pronouns, adjective).